# SQLite3 python consulta

Tags: python, sql

hola empeze a hacer un curso de python con sqlite3 y quiero modificarlo para que el usuario introduzca variables y esas variables se guarden en la tabla 
supuestamente tendria que introducir nombre,apellido,ultimopago,meses que debe y total que debe en un input y despues eso pasarlo a la base
les dejo el codigo, supuestamente tengo entendido que para añadir variables es '" +variable+"'
Gracias
``
    #SQLite

```
import sqlite3

conexion= sqlite3.connect("basededatos1.db")
cursor=conexion.cursor()

nombre= str(input("Ingrese el nombre del cliente: "))
apellido= str(input("Ingrese apellido del cliente: "))
ultimopago= str(input("Ingrese el ultimo mes pago del cliente: "))
mesdebe= str(input("Ingrese meses que debe o 0: "))
totalpesos= int(input("Ingrese total que debe: "))

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO CLIENTES VALUES('" + nombre + "', '"  + apellido + "', '" + ultimopago + "', '" + mesdebe + "', '" + totalpesos + "')")



conexion.commit()
conexion.close()
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta? Puedes introducir los datos tal como lo estas poniendo. No tienes que convertir a `str()` lo que viene de un `input()`, porque ya viene de esa forma. Con Python 3.6+, una forma más sencilla de escribir la consulta puede ser empleando [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Answer (score 1):

Nunca , nunca, pero nunca uses concatenado de cadenas (`foo + bar`) o formateo de cadenas de Python (`f"{foo}, {bar}"`, `"{}, {}".format(foo, bar`), etc) para componer una query a no ser para cosas no parametrizables como el nombre de la tabla. Como mínimo es una mala práctica si se trata de un proyecto con fines personales o puede ser una bomba con la mecha muy corta si se hace algo así en una aplicación web expuesta a todo el mundo...

Al hacer lo anterior, especialmente cuando dichas cadenas vienen como entrada de un usuario sin previamente ser filtradas y saneadas, expones a tu base de datos a ataques de inyección de código. Para las cosas no parametrizables combinen también sanear los inputs antes si cabe la posibilidad de generar algún peligro.

Paramatriza la query:

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO CLIENTES VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    (nombre, apellido, ultimopago, mesdebe , totalpesos)
    )
```

El placeholder `?` puede variar en otras BD y conectores, por ejemplo por `%s`. Además puedes usar placehoders con nombre, en cuyo caso pasa un diccionario con los parámetros.

Un ejemplo reproducible mostrando su uso:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE alumnos (nombre, edad)")

nombre = "fulanito"
edad = 18

cur.execute("INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES(?, ?)", (nombre, edad))
cur.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE nombre=:nombre_alumno AND edad=:edad_alumno",
    {"nombre_alumno": nombre, "edad_alumno": edad}
    )
print(cur.fetchone())

cur.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES(?, ?)",
    (("Pepe", 23), ("María", 18))
    )
cur.execute("select * from alumnos where edad=?", (18,))
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Comment: gracias me va a venir muy bien aprender las buenas formas de la programacion te agradezco y seguire practicando no tenia idea de eso

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar este código.

```py
import sqlite3

connection_db=sqlite3.connect("basededatos1.db") # INICIAR LA CONEXIÓN A LA DB
tables_connection_db=connection_db.cursor() 

#CREAR TABLA
tables_connection_db.execute("""CREATE TABLE USUARIOS_TABLE_DB 
   (id_usuario_db INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombre_db text, 
   apellido_db text, ultimopago_db text, mesdebe_db text, totalpesos_db real)""")
connection_db.commit() # GUARDAR TABLA CREADA


#INTRODUCIR DATOS DE USUARIO 
nombre= str(input("Ingrese el nombre del cliente: "))
apellido= str(input("Ingrese apellido del cliente: "))
ultimopago= str(input("Ingrese el ultimo mes pago del cliente: "))
mesdebe= str(input("Ingrese meses que debe o 0: "))
totalpesos= int(input("Ingrese total que debe: "))

# AGREGAR A LA BASE DE DATOS EL NUEVO REGISTRO


tables_connection_db.execute("""INSERT INTO USUARIOS_TABLE_DB  
   VALUES (NULL,"{}", "{}", "{}", "{}","{}");""".format(nombre,apellido,ultimopago,mesdebe,totalpesos))

connection_db.commit() # GUARDAR EL NUEVO REGISTRO

connection_db.close() # CERRAR LA CONEXIÓN A LA DB
```

Puedes revisar si se guardo tu registro en la base de datos subiendo tu archivo (basededatos1.db) [a esta página de internet](https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/).